# Backpack Laravel Admin Incorrectly Redirects after Editing Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a CrudController created for a model using the Backpack Laravel Admin Library.

When I update the model it redirects me incorrectly to a 404 page with the message **`No query results for model [App\Models\Group].`**

It is redirecting me to the incorrect URL from what I can tell.

`admin/group/261/` instead of `admin/group/261/edit`

The model also does not update.

I have the "Save and Edit" option set on the green save button. If I try to change this I get the same error, but it doesn't update.

I'm able to save every other model correctly.

The update method in the CrudController is just the following. I've removed all the extra code.

```
public function update(){
$response = $this->traitUpdate();
return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. It was because I was referencing the Primary Key -> 'id' in the fields within the Group Crud Controller.

```
 $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'text',
            'attributes' => ['disabled' => 'disabled'],
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use id, u need delete attribute 'disabled' like this:

```
            [
                'name' => 'id',
                'label' => 'ID',
                'attributes' => [
                    'readonly' => 'readonly',
                ],
            ],
```